# Why am I getting this java.util.InputMismatchException on yet a simple code

Tags: java

I am having a really hard time taking input with Scanner. First I was writing a a bit large code but it wasn't taking input there also. So I tried on this small code but still not works. I have taken integer as an input and have wrote nextInt but still it gives me this error. I can't find a way out of it.

```
class Main {
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {


       Scanner sc = new Scanner(Sytstem.in);
       int n = sc.nextInt();

       int sum = 2+n;
       System.out.println(sum);
   
    }   
}
```

Comment: new Scanner(Sytstem.in); has a typo. Is it compiled code?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and note that you should post your actual code and if you're asking about an exception you should include the stacktrace of that exception and point out which lines of the code you've posted are mentioned in the stack trace - if none are then you may have posted the wrong piece of code.

Comment: You might be entering a non-numeric string, like a word or some special character. Try giving a good integer, say 45.